# What is an idiomatic way to remove false and nil from an Array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I came up with

```
ary.select{|v| v}
```

But is there something better?

Comment: You explicitly have both `false` and `nil` values? If so you're stuck with doing something like this instead of `compact`. If you have active support you might be able to use `blank?`

Comment: Yes, I do......

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just delete the values you don't like:

```
ary - [ nil, false ]
```

In Ruby 2.2 you can also do this to remove *falsey* values:

```
ary.select(&:itself)
```

Though that's not really shorter.

You can also do:

```
ary.delete(nil)
ary.delete(false)
```

Which does in-place modification.

Comment: Oh I didn't even know that existed :/

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for! `ary.select(&:itself)`

Comment: I started my answer after you posted and posted my answer after you had revised yours to include the content of my answer, but did not notice your edit until now. I've therefore deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's `Array#compact`, but that'll only remove `nil` values, or `reject` if you want to be more explicit about what you're doing here, but otherwise your suggestion is pretty idiomatic.

Comment: Iterating over array with AR call: `deleted = foos.map{|f| f.delete if ...}`. Then remove skips and failures.